# Inferred Argument Type Unexpected

Tags: typescript

In the following TypeScript example the compiler complains about `callback(...args);`. It says that `Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.` which is odd. When you check the typing of `callback` it reports `const callback(arg0: number & Point, arg1: number) => void` which seems outright wrong.

### Example

```js
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

interface EventMap {
  'point': (element: Point) => void;
  'empty': () => void;
  'splat': (x: number, y: number) => void;
}

class Eventer {
    private storage: EventMap;
    constructor() {
        this.storage = {
            point: () => { },
            empty: () => { },
            splat: () => { },
        };
    }
    public on<K extends keyof EventMap>(type: K, callback: EventMap[K]): void {
        this.storage[type] = callback;
    }
    public emit<K extends keyof EventMap>(type: K, ...args: Parameters<EventMap[K]>): void {
        const callback = this.storage[type];
        callback(...args);
    }
}

const ev = new Eventer();
ev.on('point', (point) => {
    console.log(point.x);
});
ev.on('empty', () => {
    console.log('nothing');
});
ev.on('splat', (x, y) => {
    console.log(`Got ${x} and ${y}`);
});

ev.emit('point', { x: 100, y: 200 });
ev.emit('empty');
ev.emit('splat', 300, 400);
```

I've taken it and reproduced it in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20EventMap%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20'point'%3A%20(element%3A%20Point)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20'empty'%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20'splat'%3A%20(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Eventer%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20storage%3A%20EventMap%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.storage%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20point%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20empty%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20splat%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20on%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventMap%3E(type%3A%20K%2C%20callback%3A%20EventMap%5BK%5D)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.storage%5Btype%5D%20%3D%20callback%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20emit%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20EventMap%3E(type%3A%20K%2C%20...args%3A%20Parameters%3CEventMap%5BK%5D%3E)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20callback%20%3D%20this.storage%5Btype%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20callback(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ev%20%3D%20new%20Eventer()%3B%0D%0Aev.on('point'%2C%20(point)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(point.x)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aev.on('empty'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('nothing')%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0Aev.on('splat'%2C%20(x%2C%20y)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Got%20%24%7Bx%7D%20and%20%24%7By%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aev.emit('point'%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%20100%2C%20y%3A%20200%20%7D)%3B%0D%0Aev.emit('empty')%3B%0D%0Aev.emit('splat'%2C%20300%2C%20400)%3B). What's also weird is that it works if you actually try to run the transpiled JavaScript. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "which seems outright wrong." --- it does not, it's an intersection of 3 types from `EventMap` functions.

Answer (score 4):

Basically the core problem here is that TypeScript tracks types, not values, and your function isn't provably correct unless you're thinking purely in terms of concrete values provided for `type`.

Consider if you had written this code:

```
const ev = new Eventer();
const rando = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "splat" : "empty";
ev.emit(rando);
```

*This is a legal call* that breaks your implementation, because `K` is `"splat" | "empty"`, and that string union maps through the event map to the argument type `[] | [number, number]`, and the provided empty list of arguments *does* satisfy one of those.

See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581

Comment: I think it is fair to say I disagree that your example "breaks my implementation". I concede that your example confuses the compiler. Though I don't really see this as a broken end-user implementation, as much as a language that isn't expressive enough to cover this case. Probably just a semantic argument. Either way I've flagged my question as a duplicate of the other stackoverflow questions linked from that GitHub issue. Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 3):

> When you check the typing of callback it reports const callback(arg0: number & Point, arg1: number) => void which seems outright wrong.

This is how the generic method parameters in TypeScript work. The compiler has only one instance of `emit` method which must work for any possible value of `K`, it does not create a separate instance for each possible value of `K`. The only way to have type-checked single instance is to have a callback which satisfies all possible types coming from `EventMap`, that's why argument types are `arg0: number & Point, arg1: number`. For example, the first one is an intersection of `number` and `Point` which is an impossible type because number and Point have nothing in common and their intersection is reduced to `never`, but formally it's the only way to satisfy signatures for all 3 varants - `'point'`, `'empty'` and `'splat'` (Note that a function with arguments is compatible with a function without arguments - because it's OK if a function just ignores its arguments).

So this is where the `expected 2 arguments` part comes from.

The explanation for `got 0 or more` again comes from the fact that `K` can be anything that extends `keyof EventMap`, including the most permissible `keyof EventMap` type itself. So, `callback(...args)` must be well-typed when `args` are `Parameters<EventMap[keyof EventMap]>` which is a union type of 3 possible arguments: `[Point] | [] | [number, number]`. When arguments is a union type, it means that actual value can be any one of the three, so `callback(...args)` must be well-typed when args are for example `[]` (second member of the union), which fails, and when typechecking fails, the compiler shows only one error message out of all failed checks that it had seen along the way.

TL; DR there is no way to type-check this kind of code without type assertion:

```
public emit<K extends keyof EventMap>(type: K, ...args: Parameters<EventMap[K]>): void {
    const callback = this.storage[type] as (...args: Parameters<EventMap[K]>) => void;
    callback(...args);
}
```

which is fine as long as you pass the correct `args` that always correspond to the `type` when calling `emit`.